# functions vs class components to handle events and attach arguments

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to choose which is the most optimized way to write a React component that has to handle an event and send some data.

Hi I am tinkering and trying to get comfortable writing react components.

This piece of code fetches some array and makes buttons out of it.
https://codepen.io/daifuco/pen/OdxWYZ

App is just the main component, nothing special about it.

My question: As you can see in the working code,  Header + GenreButton:

```
class Header extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div clasName="footer">
        {this.props.data.map((genre)=>
          <GenreButton clicky={this.props.clickytoTop}genre={genre}/>
        )}
        </div>
        )
    }
}

class GenreButton extends Component {
    handleClick = () => {
        this.props.clicky(this.props.genre)
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="genreButton" onClick={this.handleClick}>{this.props.genre}</div>
        )
    }
}
```

has the same result as Header2, which is just a functional component, but as far as I know , Header2 creates a callback every time it renders each div.

```
function Header2(props) {
    return (

        <div clasName="footer">
      {props.data.map((genre)=>
          <div className="genreButton" onClick={()=>props.clickytoTop(genre)}>
            {genre} 

      </div>)}</div>
    )
}
```

So, I understand that Header2 is not the optimal way to design it?
are Header + GenreButton more optimized? Is there any way to improve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you ever have the choice, it is usually preferable to use a stateless component, as they do not have to manage a state which would slow down your application.

To choose between one or the other, if your component needs to re-render itself, use a class, if not, use a function.

Your `GenreButton` does not need to be a class component either in this case :

```
const Header = ({ data, clickytoTop }) => ( //Deconstructs your props
    <div clasName="footer">
        {data.map((genre) =>
            <GenreButton clicky={clickytoTop} genre={genre} />
        )}
    </div>
)
```

To avoid creating a new function everytime in your render, you could use a decorated arrow function, that you will bind this way :

```
const GenreButton = ({ clicky, genre }) => <div className="genreButton" onClick={clicky(genre)}>{genre}</div>
```

The function passed in the `header` props will now have the following declaration, to handle both sets of parameters :

```
clickFunction = genre => ev => {

}
```

When calling `clicky(genre)` it will return another function capable of accepting your click event.

```
<Header clickytoTop={this.clickFunction}/>
```

Second version (same result) :

```
const Header2 = ({ data, clickytoTop }) => ( //Deconstructs your props
    <div clasName="footer">
        {data.map(genre =>
            <div className="genreButton" onClick={clickytoTop(genre)}>{genre}</div>
        )}
    </div>
)
```

Comment: The first call made to the function is a decorator, it does not really call it but simply sets the first value (`genre`) and then returns another function capable of handling another value. Calling the function in a single instruction would look like the following : `clickytoTop(genre)(ev)`. `clickytoTop(genre)` will only decorate your function, costing close to nothing on performance.